# how to populate a jtable in java using mongo driver

Tags: java, swing, mongodb

I am trying to populate a jtable from the data I get using mongo driver in java ,This is my code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*"+textArea.getText()+".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("content:encoded", pattern);

DBCursor cursor = blogTable.find(query);

while (cursor.hasNext())
{
    chatArea.append("\n"+cursor.next().toString()); //I want to populate the jtable here instead of just appending in the JtextArea
}//End of while
```

Also I can't project the field(s) I want , I mean I only need one column (i.e title) but I  get all the columns in the result

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for `JTabel`.

Here is simple example for you:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public Example() {
        JTable table = new JTable(model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new Object[]{"data"}));
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        JButton populate = new JButton("populate");
        populate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*"+textArea.getText()+".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                //BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("content:encoded", pattern);
                //DBCursor cursor = blogTable.find(query);
                //while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                //  model.addRow(new Object[]{cursor.next().toString()});
                //}

            }
        });
        add(populate,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Example frame = new Example();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`populate` button get data from your BD and in `while` loop add new rows to table model.

Comment: thanks it works, I know I am being greedy, but do you know how I can project my result in the result I get in the mongo query

Comment: sorry, but for that i can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

For getting the projection of fields, you should pass the DBObject for projection,

`DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, projectionQuery);`

The projection is The DBObject in form of key-value pair.
where,

key is the name of field you want to project.
value can be either 0 or 1.
0 - means exclude the particular column from result set.
1 - means include the particular column in result set.

For more info, see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).